# Проверить, во всех ли словах буквы расположены в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c

> Дан текст.
>
> 1. Проверить, во всех ли словах буквы расположены в алфавитном порядке, вывести слова, к которым это **не** относится.
> 2. Введенный с клавиатуры символ во всем тексте заменить на символ подчеркивания.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char text[80];
    int i=0,size = 26;
    puts("Ведите вашу строку:");
    gets(text);
    printf("\nИсходная строка: %s", text);
```

Проблема в цикле ниже, хотела сделать так, чтобы пробегалось по строке от первого до последнего элемента, и, если левый элемент больше или равен правом, то это не алфавитный порядок. Но не вышло.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (text [i] < text[i - 1])
    gets (text);
}

char symb;
puts("\n");
puts("Vvedite simvol");

scanf("%c",&symb);

for( i = 0;i < size; i++)
    if(text[i] == symb)
        text[i]='_';

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(i>0) printf(" ");
    printf("%c",text[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Не работает мой код, он не выполняет поставленные задачи, я его прикрепила что бы могли указать на ошибки в нем

Comment: Суть stackoverflow заключает в том, чтобы Вы сказали какие у Вас ошибки и при каких случаях они происходят, и пользователи уже помогают найти их решение, а не в том, что остальные их искали за Вас и предлагали решения, советую ознакомиться со справкой о том, как задавать вопросы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: В тексте могут быть как строчные, так и прописные буквы?

Comment: А вообще, вопрос - дубликат (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756290/). Закрыть не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, начнем сначала:

1) не используйте gets() - эта ф-ция опасна, так как запросто приводит к выходу за пределы массива. Лучше пользуйтесь fgets().

2) лучше не использовать "голые" числа в коде - объявляйте константы.

3) в цикле, где, я так понял,проверяете алфавитный порядок, вы начинаете с 0 - таким образом у вас i-1 == -1 при входе в цикл

4) зачем вы сново хотите начать ввод после проверки на алфавитный порядок?

5) если длинна text == 80, то почему используете size, который равен 26?